# Remmina accessing /admin account

Tags: ubuntu, remmina

I have access to two Azure servers. Let's assume that the first one's IP is 1.2.3.4:3389 and the second one's IP is 4.3.2.1:61352

On my windows machine, the RDP files that I've been using have the following settings, respectively

```
full address:s:1.2.3.4:3389
```

and

```
full address:s:4.3.2.1:61352 /admin
```

How do I specify the "/admin" part in Remmina? I'm able to connect to 1.2.3.4 without problem but cannot as yet connect to 4.3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the saved connection entry and on its Advanced tab check
"Attach to console".

The names box/console is the former option name for `/admin`.

Comment: I did think of that. It doesn't work, sadly. The Azure box is Windows 2012 if that matters

Comment: The above is the only explanation I know. If it doesn't work, the conclusion might be that it was lost.